# How to resolve Varnish FetchError "Timed out reusing backend connection"

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am seeing frequent errors Varnish  FetchError "Timed out reusing backend connection". Checked couple of blogs, but not find any resolution. Could you please help?

- BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
- BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 37849780
- VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
- VCL_return     fetch
- BackendOpen    36 NODEJS_2 xx.xx.xx.xx 9000 yy.yy.yy.yy 43309
- Timestamp      Bereq: 1605444526.456709 0.000102 0.000102
- FetchError     Timed out reusing backend connection
- BackendClose   36 NODEJS_2
- Timestamp      Beresp: 1605444571.456893 45.000285 45.000183
- Timestamp      Error: 1605444571.456900 45.000292 0.000006
- BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
- BerespStatus   503
- BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
- BerespHeader   Date: Sun, 15 Nov 2020 12:49:31 GMT
- BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
- VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
- BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
- VCL_return     deliver
- Storage        malloc Transient
- Length         285
- BereqAcct      2940 185 3125 0 0 0
- End

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Timestamp Beresp: 1605444571.456893 45.000285 45.000183` tag in your *VSL* output indicates that your backend took  `45.000183` seconds to generate its response, which triggered the `first_byte_timeout`.

In reality, your backend probably needed more than 45 seconds to generate the output, but *Varnish* just gave up after it hit the timeout.

Here are your options:

1. Increase the `first_byte_timeout` runtime parameter to a better number
2. Examine why your backend it taking so long

Although option 1 is theoretically viable, you really want to go for option 2, and figure out why it is taking so long for the backend to respond.